# What is the error in this numba function about?

Tags: python, recursion, numba

I have written this python function, which I believed was going to port to numba. Unfortunately it does not, and I'm not sure I understand the error:
**`Invalid use of getiter with parameters (none)`**.

Does it need to know the type of the generator? Is it because it returns tuples of variable length?

```py
from numba import njit

# @njit
def iterator(N, k):
    r"""Numba implementation of an iterator over tuples of N integers,
    such that sum(tuple) == k.

    Args:
        N (int): number of elements in the tuple
        k (int): sum of the elements
    Returns:
        tuple(int): a tuple of N integers
    """
    if N == 1:
        yield (k,)
    else:
        for i in range(k+1):
            for j in iterator(N-1, k-i):
                yield (i,) + j
```

EDIT

Thanks to Jerome for the tips. Here's the solution I eventually wrote (I started from the left):

```py
import numpy as np
from numba import njit

@njit
def next_lst(lst, i, reset=False):
    r"""Computes the next list of indices given the current list
    and the current index.
    """
    if lst[i] == 0:
        return next_lst(lst, i+1, reset=True)
    else:
        lst[i] -= 1
        lst[i+1] += 1
    if reset:
        lst[0] = np.sum(lst[:i+1])
        lst[1:i+1] = 0
        i = 0
    return lst, i

@njit
def generator(N, k):
    r"""Goes through all the lists of indices recursively.
    """
    lst = np.zeros(N, dtype=np.int64)
    lst[0] = k
    i = 0
    yield lst
    while lst[-1] < k:
        lst, i = next_lst(lst, i)
        yield lst
```

This gives the correct result and it's jitted!

```py
for lst in generator(4,2):
    print(lst)

[2 0 0 0]
[1 1 0 0]
[0 2 0 0]
[1 0 1 0]
[0 1 1 0]
[0 0 2 0]
[1 0 0 1]
[0 1 0 1]
[0 0 1 1]
[0 0 0 2]
```

Comment: That looks recursive...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One problem comes from the **variable-sized tuple** output. Indeed, tuples are like structure with different types in Numba. They are very different from lists as opposed to Python (AFAIK, in Python, a tuple is roughly just list that cannot be mutated). In Numba, a tuple of 1 item and 2 items are two different type. They cannot be *unified* to a more generic type. The thing is the return falue of a function have to be a unique type. Thus, Numba refuse to compile the function in nopython mode. The only way to solve this problem in Numba is to **use lists**.

That being said, even with list, an error is reported. The documentation states that:

> Most recursive call patterns are supported. The only restriction is that the recursive callee **must have a control-flow path that returns without recursing**.

I think this this restriction is not fulfilled here since there is no return statement. That being said, the function should implicitly return a generator (which have a type depending on... the recursive function itself). Note also that the [support of generators](https://numba.readthedocs.io/en/stable/developer/generators.html) is quite new and it seems reasonable that recursive generators are not well supported. I advise you to open an issue on the Numba github as I am not sure this is an expected behaviour.

Note that it is probably more efficient to implement this function without recursion. By the way, this function will certainly only be faster if it is called from a Numba function and not CPython.

Comment: Thank you. How does one implement it without recursion? With an extra argument that's kind of a 'state'?

Comment: Yes a kind of. I think you can start with the `[0, 0, ..., 0, k]` list/array, then decrement the last (nth) item while incrementing the previous. When you reach 0, you need to increment the (n-2)th item and reset the right part with `[0, 0, ..., 0, k-sum(left_part)]`. You need to repeat this process in a while loop until the first item is set to k and needs to be incremented.